# Lists: First Name Always Quoted

Tags: r

Consider the two lists

```
> list('a' = 1, 'b' = 2)
$`a`
[1] 1
$b
[1] 2

> list( z = 0, a = 1, b = 2) # added space just in case
$`z`
[1] 0
$a
[1] 1
$b
[1] 2
```

Why is the name of the first (and only the first) element quoted?

I found a similar issue [on this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52389448/r-unwanted-quotation-marks-in-tibblelst-names) but it didn't explain (or at least I failed to understand) why the above occurs.

---

**PS**

When accessing list elements by names using the `$` notation the problem does *not* appear, i.e. `l1$a` works just as well as `l1$'a'` (with " ` " instead of " ' ").

Comment: @markus my bad - did not find that one. I'll remove my question.

Comment: Don't remove it! It will help future googlers that have the same question.

Comment: @markus Alright I won't. What is the modus operandi in such cases?

Comment: I voted to close as dupe. This is the usual way, I guess.

Comment: See this [R-Devel](https://www.mail-archive.com/r-devel@r-project.org/msg39709.html) thread.